# Hover all previous li of same parent when hovering on one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have multiple div on page with multiple li inside that

```
<div>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>


<div>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
```

what I want is when anyone hovering on any li it will trigger hover on that and its all previous li of particular div as well or at least add any class on it and when hover out remove class from all that li

Comment: It is not a good practice to have `li` within `div`. `li` should be within `ul` or `ol` tag :)

Comment: ok assume it that div as ul

Comment: why not write some code (js,css,markup) make mistake and then post here :) so that it can be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** to select all previous `li`, and **[`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** for handling the hover event

**Note:** Your html is not valid. Element li not allowed as child of element `div`, `li` should be child of `ul` or `ol`

```js
$('div li').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover').prevAll('li').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover').prevAll('li').removeClass('hover');
})
```

```css
.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is a `<li></li>` allowed as a child of a `<div></div>`? so far as I can remember we can't do that... they must be children of a `<ol></ol>` or `<ul></ul>`...

you can check that and then try with prevAll()

regards!